# How to send a message to a specific channel with Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I try all the possibilities of stack overflow on this subject and that doesn't work for me, I think that outdated. I'm on Discord.JS V13.6

So, for the moment, I have this :

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('my_id-channel');
channel.send('content');
```

I take my_id-channel with a right click on the channel → copy id

My error :
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord: Get channel by ID returns undefined / null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68139964/discord-get-channel-by-id-returns-undefined-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a switch ON my brain, I understand my stupid script -_-

I didn't know I'm supposed to write my script here :

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
    // HERE MY CODE
});
```

So now that's work ^^'

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the channel doesn't currently exist in the ChannelManager's cache, try using the [ChannelManager.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) method.

Your code should look something like this:

`client.channels.fetch('my_id-channel').then(channel => channel.send('content'));`

If you're unfamiliar, a cache is a local temporary storage used to save data temporarily so you don't have to do operations which may take a long time (i.e. requesting information from a server). Essentially this means that a cache is volatile and you can't always guarantee what you're looking for is there.

I suspect in this case the channel has not previously been retrieved so it does not exist in the cache yet.

Comment: With your method, I have this code error : 
`client.channels.fetch('my_id-channel').then(channel => channel.send('content')); TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null
`
I also try with integer directly for id channel and I have this error :
`DiscordAPIError: Unknown Channel`
I don't take the good id ?